# Angular.js: filter ng-repeat by absence in array

Tags: angularjs, repeater, filtering

I need to filter items in ng-repeat so that only the items which not appear in alreadyAddedValues() array will be shown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="v in values() | filter: { ????? } ">{{value.name}}</li>
</ul>

$scope.values() = function(){
    ................
}

$scope.alreadyAddedValues() = function()
{
    //returns an array
}
```

The search of an already added value should perform by `value.shortName`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can, for example, use a custom function to do the filtering:

```
<li ng-repeat="v in values() | filter:filterAlreadyAdded ">{{value.name}}</li>
```

On the controller:

```
$scope.filterAlreadyAdded = function(item) {
    // filter logic here...
    // return false if item already added, true otherwise
};
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/5VbCJ/

Comment: I made an alternate fiddle to pass pass the array of already added values to make it a bit more generic. Located here http://jsfiddle.net/4MBbw/